# DataGrid - iterate over rows and access cell values of each row

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, datagrid

In *C# WPF* I have a **DataGrid**-object. To fill the **DataGrid**-object with values I am setting the **DataGrid.ItemsSource**-property like this:

```
List<SomeClass> someClassList = new List<SomeClass>();
//adding elements to someClassList (omitted for brevity)
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = someClassList;
```

This works and I am able to see all the elements added to `someClassList` inside the **DataGrid**.

After the **user clicks a button**, I want to save all contents inside that **DataGrid** to an **XML-file**.

I thought it would therefore be clever to *iterate over the rows* of the **DataGrid**. With each iteration i could *access the values inside the cells of one row at a time* and write it to an **XML-file**.

To perform such an iteration I have written this code:

```
foreach (SomeClass someClassElement in myDataGrid.Items)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("cell-A = " + someClassElement.propertyA +
                    "cell-B = " + someClassElement.propertyB +
                    "cell-C = " + someClassElement.propertyC);
}
```

Unfortunately executing it (by clicking a button) causes an **InvalidCastException**, although the **WritLine**-method is able to print every cell value into the **Output-window**.

**How can I perform the iteration without an InvalidCastException ?**

**Is there a cleverer approach to save the DataGrid content to an XML-File ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over `myDataGrid.ItemsSource` instead of `myDataGrid.Items` and you will get the `SomeClass` instances.